# The New MAC Pro and Protools

Tags: pro-tools, mac, new

I am a lecturer at a University and there are some consideration for buying the latest MAC Pro (The Trash can) to run our Protools 10. There has been serious apprehension regarding this from the money people as they feel it is too early to buy such a new design- especially when it is very difficult to upgrade. We work on a 5 year plan whereby after 5 years, the old stuff get replaced.

Has anyone had any experiences with the new MAC Pro and if so, were they negative/positive. What are your feelings regarding the new model and the difficulty in getting it upgraded. I know it is incredibly powerful but I am also looking at the fact that the model is in its early stages.

Thanks

Comment: While this is tangentially related to sound design, this sounds much more like a general computer question as none of the concerns are really Sound Design specific.  You may want to try asking on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/), the Apple Q/A community on Stack Exchange.  You may also want to phrase it in to a more answerable question, such as "is getting this new model worth the risks for a university studio?"  Alternately, if there is an audio specific question here, please edit the question to clarify that question.

Comment: Perhaps it's more interesting/on topic for sound design, if you could add what type work will be done with the machines? And just to give a hint: have you looked into a mac mini?